# Efeito de escrita em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um código de efeito de escrita, porém funciona só quando atualiza a página, eu queria que rodasse automaticamente, alguém pode dar uma força?

Abaixo está o código. o que preciso trocar ou acrescentar para que seja infinito, sem precisar ficar atualizando a página?

```
 function typeWriter(elemento) {
    const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
    elemento.innerHTML = '';
    textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
    });
  }
  const titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
  typeWriter(titulo);
```

Obs: a escrita tá vindo de um `h1` que coloquei no HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Adicione outro `setTimeout` chamando a mesma função quando o índice do `forEach` alcançar a última letra do texto. O tempo desse intervalo você soma com o `75 * i`. Por exemplo, se você quer repetir o efeito após 1 segundo dele ter terminado:

```
75 * i + 1000
```

Ficará assim:

```js
function typeWriter(elemento) {
   const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
   elemento.innerHTML = '';
   textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
      if(textoArray.length-1 == i){
         setTimeout(() => typeWriter(elemento), 75 * i + 1000);
      }
   });
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```html
<h1>teste de escrita</h1>
```

### Adicionando uma barra no final

Coloque a barra `|` no final do texto e altere o script usando `.pop()` para remover a barra da array e a forma de alterar o innerHTML:

```js
function typeWriter(elemento) {
   const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
   textoArray.pop();
   elemento.innerHTML = '';
   textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML = elemento.innerHTML.replace("|", "") + letra +"|", 75 * i);
      if(textoArray.length-1 == i){
         setTimeout(() => typeWriter(elemento), 75 * i + 1000);
      }
   });
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```html
<h1>teste de escrita|</h1>
```

Comment: muitooo obrigado.. deu certo!

só por curiosidade, como que faço para colocar aquela barra ?

Comment: Adicionei na resposta. Veja se resolve.